# encode and decode characters not allowed on windows file system

Tags: php, fopen

I need to create files from strings (`fopen`) on windows, localhost.

The strings may contain characters not allowed on windows system:

`\/:*?"<>|`

Is it possible to encode those characters, so the files are created with encoded names, and decode them while getting them back on php side?

If not, how can I simply remove them?

Comment: removing can be done with a [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: [this tool](https://www.splitbrain.org/encode.php?u=0&w=%3Cthis+is%3Ea%3A*+f%2Fi%5Clename.xml) can help you find a fitting encoder for your needs. urlencode/urldecode might fit.